# Unable to ouptut six different items in specific column in my Powershell listview

Tags: powershell, listview, multiple-columns, listviewitem

I need help with my winform script including a listview. I have 6 items and I try to show them in a specific column.

For example, I have 6 items from $a to $f and 6 columns (1 to 6) in my listview. I need to show each of them in specific one:

($a in column 1)
($b in column 2)
($c in column 3)
...etc

Actually, all items are output in the same column, and I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, please help !

Here's an example of my code:

```
Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "New Test"
$Form.Width = 1550
$Form.Height = 800 

$Listview = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$Listview.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,10)
$Listview.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(550,10)
$Listview.AutoResizeColumns([System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle]::ColumnContent)
$Listview.View = "Details"
$Listview.FullRowSelect = $true
$Listview.GridLines = $true
$Listview.Height = 650
$Listview.Width =1500
$Listview.AllowColumnReorder = $true
$Listview.Sorting = [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder]::None  

[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Date',150)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Auteur',150)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Tache',500)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Status',100)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Assigné',150)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Commentaire',500)


$oButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$oButton.Text = "List"
$oButton.Top = 700
$oButton.Left = 350
$oButton.Width = 150
$oButton.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right 

$oButton.add_click({

$a3 = Get-Date
$b3 = Get-Date
$c3 = Get-Date
$d3 = Get-Date
$e3 = Get-Date
$f3 = Get-Date

$Entry1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Date)
$Entry2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Auteur)
$Entry3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Tache)
$Entry4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Status)
$Entry5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Assigné)
$Entry6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Commentaire) 

[void]$Listview.Items.Add($Entry1)
[void]$Entry1.SubItems.Add($a3.ToString())

[void]$Listview.Items.Add($Entry2)
[void]$Entry2.SubItems.Add($b3.ToString())

[void]$Listview.Items.Add($Entry3)
[void]$Entry3.SubItems.Add($c3.ToString())

[void]$Listview.Items.Add($Entry4)
[void]$Entry4.SubItems.Add($d3.ToString())

[void]$Listview.Items.Add($Entry5)
[void]$Entry5.SubItems.Add($e3.ToString())

[void]$Listview.Items.Add($Entry6)
[void]$Entry6.SubItems.Add($f3.ToString())

})
  
  
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()}) 
  
$Form.controls.add($oButton)
$Form.controls.add($Listview)
  
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: You are creating 6 listviewitems and putting each value in each respective first subitem. Thus putting them in the first column. Try to add them as subitems in Entry1.

Comment: Really thanks for th advice and the fast answer , i did this and it is now outputed horizontally, the issue is now the first column is skipped , could you please help about this ?

Comment: Sorry, i just handled this from my side, thanks again for your help Smorkster !!!

Comment: Now i have the same issue when i try to output multiple results per columns one below the other.. I tried something with foreach but it doesnt work , all results are in the same line. Can you please help me with this ? example foreach($lst in $a)

Comment: Think of the subitems as boxes. Everytime you call Subitems.Add, you create a new box. If you want to have data at separate rows, inside the box, you have to format the data first, keep it in a string and then put it in a subitem.

Comment: To be honest, im novice in coding and my knowledge are limited. I don't know how to do this : format the data first, keep it in a string and then put it in a subitem 
Thanks again for your patience

Comment: Easiest way is to first create the string with the first data, $var = "first row" . Then for each new row you want for the subitem, do $var += " ``nnext row" (notice the backtick "`").

Comment: Ps use only onebacktick, I dont know how to edit propeely on phone

Comment: Okay, i will check soon , once i'll be back at my office . I will give you a feedback. Thanks again

Comment: I tried but im still blocked

Answer (score 0):

To add a row to the listview, just add the data with '=' to the entry's Text-property. This will go to the first column.

To add to the other columns, you have to put them in subitems. Unfortunelty, after testing and searching, I found that you can't have a linebreak in the text of a listviewitem. To have linebreaks, you will have to switch to a DataGridView.

Below is a sample of how to add to the ListView. This have been tested in your code, and it works

```
[void]$Listview.Items.Add($Entry1)
$Entry1.Text = $a3.ToString()
[void]$Entry1.SubItems.Add("Claudé")
[void]$Entry1.SubItems.Add("Shop")
[void]$Entry1.SubItems.Add("Done")
[void]$Entry1.SubItems.Add($a3.AddDays(-3).ToString())
[void]$Entry1.SubItems.Add("Need more cake")
```